# How to avoid closing browser tab when deleting a word in Jupyter terminal?

Tags: firefox, jupyter

When I'm in a Jupyter terminal, I often use the `Ctrl-w` bash shortcut to delete a word. Unfortunately both Firefox and Chromium close my browser tab when I do this. In their quest to simplify settings, browsers don't allow to disable this keybinding anymore (it was possible with older versions).

Firefox documentation recommends the Saka Key extension in order to customize keybindings, but I found that while this extension allows to add new key bindings, it doesn't replace existing one, so `Crtl-w` still closes tabs.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://superuser.com/a/1387208. Havent tried this though

Answer (score 2):

- [userChrome.js](https://github.com/nuchi/firefox-quantum-userchromejs) for example the following code to remove the Ctrl+B keybinding.

```
var key = document.getElementById('viewBookmarksSidebarKb');
if (key) key.remove();
```

- [Write your own js](https://github.com/janakaud/js-for-firefox/blob/master/keyconfig/All.js), see code at bottom `var _mappings = {` (and paste it into [Browser Console] after you launch Firefox)
- [Binary hacking firefox](https://github.com/janakaud/js-for-firefox/blob/master/keyconfig/All.js) (re-run the hack script after every Firefox upgrade)

([Credits goes to](https://superuser.com/questions/821594/firefox-change-disable-default-keyboard-shortcut-configuration))